# Lag when too many Marker Using ClusterItem Android Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I use the util library maps android for Cluster item. 
I have many marker but It's too slow on navigation.
Is there a way to optimize this apps?

You can see this video : https://youtu.be/lboDrBmI6xo

Comment: Did you found a solution? I've the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are suggestions to [Optimize Maps with Many
 Makers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers):

> 1. One approach at simplification is to render markers on the server. Google provides two services built into the API that make this easy to
>      achieve: FusionTablesLayer and KmlLayer. If you'd prefer to perform
>      computations on your own server, this can be accomplished by creating
>      a custom overlay from imagery that is pre-rendered, or rendered on the
>      fly.
> 2. Another useful optimization technique involves viewport marker management: restricting the markers rendered on the map into only
>      those that exist within the viewable area.
> 3. If you still want to display many markers on the map, consider creating a custom overlay that displays markers with minimal
>      functionality. This approach may garner performance improvements over
>      standard markers provided by the API.

Read more on the docs for optimization tips.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that marker clustering is the way to go on Android and we have a utility library to use for this. You can check it out [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)